# How to Feed Two Lists of Data into a parLapply Function?

Tags: r

I have a list of animal tracking data that I'm trying to calculate kde home ranges for using the ctmm package. I've already calculated these home range values, however I'm trying to adapt my code to run in parallel to save processing time. The issue I'm running into so far is that my home range estimates from my parallelized code do not match my original home range estimates. After some playing around, I think the error is resulting from the parLapply function only using the first object in the M.IID list instead of each subsequent M.IID object that corresponds to a particular telemetry object. Is there any way I can modify my code to feed the correct M.IID value into the parLapply function for each telemetry object? Thanks!

```
#Loading libraries
library(ctmm)
library(parallel)

#Reading in the example data associated with the ctmm package
data("buffalo")

#Adding an ID column to all lists
for(i in 1:length(buffalo)){
  buffalo[[i]][7]<-names(buffalo[i])
  names(buffalo[[i]])[7]<-"ID"
  
}

#Setting up a cluster for parallel processing
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

M.IID <-parLapply(cl,buffalo,ctmm.fit) #Fitting the IID model for KDE calculation
KDE <- parLapply(cl,buffalo,CTMM=M.IID, units=FALSE,akde) #Calculate KDE range size using IID model

#Creating a list of all summary objects for each kde estimate
summ<-list(summary(KDE[[1]]),summary(KDE[[2]]),summary(KDE[[3]]),summary(KDE[[4]]),
        summary(KDE[[5]]),summary(KDE[[6]]))

#Extrcting just the KDE estimate and putting them into a list object
HR.values<-list(summ[[1]][[2]][[2]],summ[[2]][[2]][[2]],summ[[3]][[2]][[2]],summ[[4]][[2]][[2]],
                summ[[5]][[2]][[2]],summ[[6]][[2]][[2]])

#Adding names to the list of home range estimate values
names(HR.values)<-names(buffalo)

#stop parallel
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: You may need to create an anonymous function: `KDE <- parLapply(cl, seq_along(buffalo), \(i) akde(buffalo[[i]], CTMM=M.IID[[i]], units=FALSE))`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I seem to run into an issue when I use your provided code, and I was wondering if you'd be able to take a look. I keep getting the following error: Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  6 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "akde". I do have the ctmm package installed, and the akde function works outside of this code chunk, so I'm not sure where the issue is coming from. Any ideas?

Comment: Before `parLapply`, you need to load the package on the cluster nodes: `clusterEvalQ(cl, library("ctmm"))`

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to fix the first error! I was getting a similar error saying that the buffalo object could not be found, but I think I've fixed that by loading the buffalo object in the same way: `clusterEvalQ(cl, data("buffalo"))`. Now I'm getting this error message: `Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  6 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'M.IID' not found`. I've tried using the clusterEval function to load the object, but nothing's worked so far. Any ideas? Sorry about all the questions, I think it's almost there!

Comment: I think you're looking for `clusterExport`.